# Crystal Reports - Record Selection - Syntax Error

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I do have a crystal report which when I run it, it produces an error, which I believe is related to the code under Selection Formulas > Record Selection.

Under Record Selection Formula, here is my code:

```
{SN_Contact2.cust_commercial_id_status} = "8-Client" and
{SN_Contact2.CUST_Life_Renewal_Date} > DateTime (2015, 12, 31, 00, 00, 00)
```

Error message that pops up in crytal reports:

"Division by Zero"

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this is the error in record selection formula.. you are dividing nothing here

Comment: as @Siva said that is not a record selection formula error. Start looking for a division formula you have on the report and do an if statement to return 0 when your divisor = 0

Answer (score 0):

There is no division for sure, but I think you need to check values of your variables, maybe there is some NULL...